# Android use defaut communication app of phone for send message

Tags: android, email, sms

I would like to create my android app as stated below.

When user click on a button, it will redirect to the list of different communication applications (such as  SMS, Email). And he can send some information to developer.

Please propose me to refer some code on this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Thanks @Raju Subramanian

Answer (score 0):

To display the list of different communication applications need to use list view you can refer here http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

And to send SMS or Email refer here http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-send-sms-in-android